# Implicitly calling a constructor of an inaccessible virtual base class

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, clang, virtual-inheritance

Consider the code below. Both g++ and clang++ complain (correctly) that the constructor `A(int)` is private in class `D`. Note that, as `A` is a virtual base class of `D`, `A` has to be initialized in the *mem-initializer* of class `D`, the most derived class, according to §12.6.2/7 in C++11. See [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0598e02bf470d41e).

```
class A {
public:
    A(int i) : x(i) { }
    A() : x(1) {}
    int x;
};

class B : private virtual A {
protected:
    B(int i) : A(i) { } };

class C : public B, private virtual A {
protected:
    C(int i) : A(i), B(i) { }
};

class D : public C {
public:
    D() : A(1), C(3) { }
};

int main() {
    D d;
}
```

But both compilers don't bother with the fact that the default constructor for class `A` is also private in `D`, i.e., both compile and execute the code normally, if we define the constructor for `D` as follows:

```
D() : C(3) {}
```

And this is wrong, as far as I can tell.

Note that both compilers fail to compile (correctly) if we define:

```
D() : A(), C(3) {}
```

Comment: You might want to add a live example that shows the case your are puzzled about i.e. `D() : C(3) {}`

Comment: @RSahu Even for the case `D(): C(3) {}` pointed above? I'm asking this because I really don't know the difference between the compiler I used in Coliru (the standard std=C++11) and 4.7.3 that you mentioned above

Comment: @RSahu With `D() : C(3)`, I get no error with GCC 4.7.4. Which command-line options are you using with 4.7.3 to get an error for that?

Comment: I got the same error `error: 'class A A::A' is inaccessible` on ideone: http://ideone.com/n9ywWo

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Here you go: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/df0b851b4f6ab1ac

Comment: @hvd, I get the same behavior, which corroborates the OP's concern.

Comment: Amusingly, on MSVC, the code compiles even when `D() : A(1), C(3) {}` is used... that makes absolutely no sense to me.

Comment: @RSahu But "correctly", according to the OP, would mean getting an error. If you're getting the same behaviour as I am, and you're saying that behaviour is correct, then I'm missing something.

Comment: @wolfPack88 But that seems to be a bug in Visual Studio. I tried that too.

Comment: @hvd, no you didn't miss anything. I was confused a little bit. I removed my comments.

Comment: FWIW, Intel, Sun and even TenDRA agree that it's not an error. Making it most likely that there is actually some explanation to make the code valid. But I don't have that explanation readily available.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> But both compilers don't bother with the fact that the default constructor for class `A` is also private in `D`,

No, that default constructor isn't private. The base class `A` is private, but its default constructor is public.

And that's why it works: when naming base classes in the *ctor-initializer*, the named base classes have to be accessible, because access control applies to names, and a few special exceptions where the standard says that implicitly called functions still have to be accessible.

When base classes are implicitly constructed, those base classes are not named. They are simply default-initialized (per 12.6.2p8), and default-initialization merely checks whether the constructor is accessible (per 8.5p7).

You can tell that the problem is with the name of the base class by not using the private inherited name of the base class, but by using the globally accessible name `::A`:

```
D() : ::A(1), C(3) { }
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/132e08b8319cf28b)

Comment: The default constructor is public only when it's not user-provided.

Comment: @Belloc That makes no sense. Please re-read your comment, think about what you want to say, and then rephrase it.

Comment: §12.1/5 (C++11) `An implicitly-declared default constructor is an inline public member of its class.`

Comment: @Belloc I'm talking about the default constructor you defined. `A() : x(1) {}`. You put that under `public:`, so that default constructor is public. Perhaps you're thinking of some other language, where "default constructor" refers only to a compiler-generated constructor? That's not the case in C++. 12.1p5, before your quote: "A *default* constructor for a class `X` is a constructor of class `X` that can be called without an argument."

Comment: Then answer me, how does the constructor `A(int) ` is privately inherited in D and the user-provided default constructor is not?

Comment: @Belloc None of the constructors are inherited.

Comment: Ok, how does the constructor `A(int)` is inaccessible in `D` and the user-provided constructor is not? They are both public in `A`.

Comment: @Belloc They are both accessible. However, the base class `A` is not. That's what I'm pointing out in my answer: `D() : A()` or `D() : A(3)` doesn't fail because the constructor in inaccessible, it fails because the base class is inaccessible.

Comment: I beginning to understand what you said in your answer. But where is this stated in the Standard?

Comment: @Belloc 12.6.2p8 just says subobjects are default-initialized, like I mentioned already, without any prohibition on accessibility aside from indirectly that of the default constructor. It's the lack of prohibition that makes it valid. When you *do* name the base class in the initializer list, then the general rule of 11p4 applies ("Access control is applied uniformly to all names, whether the names are referred to from declarations or expressions. ")

Comment: You may be right, but I'm having a lot of difficulty accepting your interpretation, by just reading the Standard. For instance, when you say: `They are both accessible. However, the base class A is not.`, that doesn't make much sense to me. And if that is the case, I think the Standard should be more clear about this.

Comment: @Belloc The standard isn't meant as a tutorial, it's meant to be as unambiguous as possible even if that makes it more difficult to understand. There are indeed a lot of aspects that you wouldn't easily understand just by reading the standard. The thing with the base class is that every class has an injected-class-name, which mostly gets treated as an ordinary member, including during inheritance of base class members. `struct A { };` has a member `A` which is effectively a typedef of `struct A`. `struct B : private A { };` then inherits that injected-class-name `A`, and makes it `private`.

Comment: @Belloc So when you then have `struct C : B { C() { delete new A(); } };` (which is just silly, and serves merely as an example), that's invalid, even though it isn't an attempt to access the private base class of `B`.

Comment: @Belloc And base class initialisers in a constructor initialisation list are specified by referring to types, not by referring to constructors. Those types may be specified in any way that types get specified, including typedefs, including injected-class-names, but the names used in specifying the type have to be accessible just as any other names. Does that make sense?

Comment: `12.6.2p8 just says subobjects are default-initialized, like I mentioned already, without any prohibition on accessibility aside from indirectly that of the default constructor. It's the lack of prohibition that makes it valid.` I would say that this is not entirely correct. §12.6.2/8 refers to §8.5 and in §8.5/6 first bullet point we have: `if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type (Clause 9), the default constructor for T is called (and the initialization is ill-formed if T has no accessible default constructor);`.

Comment: @Belloc I mentioned that already in my answer: "and default-initialization merely checks whether the constructor is accessible (per 8.5p7)." But the constructor is accessible, so that isn't a problem.

Comment: I finally understood what's going on here. Thanks for the great answer (+1).

Comment: @curiousguy If you've got a better answer, please post it, but I explained thoroughly why I believe this to be correct, and a comment that amounts to little more than "no" isn't going to convince me otherwise.

Comment: Simply put, any member found via private inheritance is private and inaccessible. The std is unreadable on ctor invocations but the intent is clear.

Comment: @curiousguy The constructor isn't found via inheritance. That's the whole point of my answer. gcc, clang and Intel are in agreement on this, by the way.

Comment: Interesting. Which are the declarations "found via inheritance"? Can you point to the exhaustive list?

Comment: @curiousguy I'm not sure why you put "found via inheritance" in quotes. It makes it look as if it's a term I've coined, but I've just used your words. Since constructors aren't inherited in the first place, they cannot possibly be found via inheritance. Anything other than constructors isn't relevant to this question and answer, so I'm not going to look for a list.

Comment: So access control doesn't apply uniformly to all declaration?